# Example of super method

Tags: javascript, inheritance

The following code snippet is borrowed from Crockford's book from chapter covering Functional type of inheritance (as opposed to Pseudoclassical and Prototypal inheritance).

By some reason I am unable to run it in jsfiddle.net because it always returns the error:

> "43:20 Uncaught TypeError:
> Cannot set property 'name' of undefined"

However the main question I have to ask is about the following code line:

> that.get_name = function (n) {return 'like '+ super_get_name() +
> 'baby';};

Why does the above function require argument n in brackets? Is this because we envisage the possibility of use of method "purr"?

```
 var mammal = function (spec) {
    var that = {};
    that.get_name = function () {
        return spec.name;
    };
    that.says = function () {
        return spec.saying || '';
    };
    return that;
};
var myMammal =
    mammal({
    name: 'Herb'
});

var cat = function (spec) {
    spec.saying =
        spec.saying || 'meow';
    var that =
        mammal(spec);
    that.purr = function (n) {
        var i,
        s = '';
        for (i =
                9; i < n; i += 1) {
            if (s) {
                s += '-'
            }
            s += 'r';
        }
        return s;
    };
    that.get_name = function () {
        return that.says() + ' '
         + spec.name + ' '
         + that.says();
    };
    return that;
};
var myCat =
    cat({
    name: 'Henrietta'
});

Object.method('superior', function (name) {
    var that =
        this,
    method =
        that[name];
    return function () {
        return method.apply(that, arguments);
    };
});

var coolcat = function (spec) {
    var that =
        cat(spec),
    super_get_name =
        that.superior('get_name');
    that.get_name = function (n) {
        return 'like '
         + super_get_name() + 'baby';
    };
    return that;
};
var myCoolCat =
    coolcat({
    name: 'Bix'
});
var name =
    myCoolCat.get_name();
```

Comment: First error is a typo right at the start: `that.get_.name` => `that.get_name`. Also note that all of this is really outdated. JavaScript has a `class` keyword now, and supports writing actual classes.

Comment: Sh*t. Sorry. That's my typo. Corrected.

Comment: Right, so taken this very outdated method of creating classes for granted, assigning a function for later use allows stating parameters. The `purr` method uses a parameter `n`, because you're supposed to pass a number when calling it. `get_name` doesn't need a parameter like that, so you can safely remove it.

Comment: Thanks. The book is of 2008. Have there been  too many changes in Javascript since then? I've corrected the typo, but JSFiddle keeps warning "<a class='gotoLine' href='#85:8'>85:8</a> Uncaught TypeError: Object.method is not a function"

Comment: The line number is referring to the combined source code of the frame in the bottom right part; in your code it is referring to the actual `Object.method(...);` line. I'll go ahead and assume that you aren't supposed to literally write `Object.method` but rather something like `myCat.purr()` (since myCat is an Object and has a method called purr)

Comment: Also yeah, a book from 2008 is basically ancient at this point. There have been loads of new features and standards added to JS in the last years especially.

Answer (score 0):

> Why does the above function require argument n in brackets?

It doesn't. `n` never gets assigned or read. It is completely superfluous.